# Determine if number is highly composite

Tags: r, function

I have troubles with my code that is supposed to determine whether a given natural number is [highly composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number) or not. So far, I have come up with this:

```
 ex33 <- function(x){
  fact <- function(x) {
    x <- as.integer(x)
    div <- seq_len(abs(x))
    factors <- div[x %% div == 0L]
    return(factors)
  }
  k <- length(fact(x))
  check <- NULL
  tocheck <- c(1:(x-1))[-fact(x)]
  for (i in tocheck) {
    l <- length(fact(i))
    if (l>=k){
      check[i]<-1
      break
    }else{
      check[i]<-0
    }
  }
  if (1 %in% check){
    return(FALSE)
  }else{
    return(TRUE)
  }
}
```

I know, this is quite ineffective and slow, but I could not find another algorithm to speed this function up.

Comment: But if this algorithm is working you are done.

Comment: An efficient algorithm for this is non-trivial.  So I think that this would be too broad a question for here.  Consider migrating it to https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic perhaps?